# Determine Number of Tokens - BATCH

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, token

I'm currently working on a mass user creation script through PowerShell and Batch. At the moment the script is 95 lines and is the largest script I've ever written in Batch.

I want the script to be as automated as possible and plan to give it to clients that need help creating a mass number of users. To do this, I have a 21 line settings file and one of the variables that I need is the full domain name (This is needed for dsadd)

The problem with this is that users may have any number of variables for this - anywhere from two in testlabs to four in places like schools. I am so far able to separate the tokens however I need them all stored as variables like %%a, %%b and not to store everything as %%a. The number of tokens will be dynamic so I need some sort of solution to this. Something like this (Yes I know this is not the correct syntax):

```
if number of tokens=4 (
dsadd "cn=%%a,ou=%%b,dc=%DSuffix1%,dc=%DSuffix2%,dc=%DSuffix3%,dc=%Dsuffix4% )
```

In that line %%a and %%b are variables in another for loop later in the code that reads from a user list excel file. I would need something like that for anything from two tokens to four tokens. I don't mind if the solution to this is not purely BATCH however that is my preferred option.

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the for loop I have at the moment, this is nested in another larger for loop that adds the users:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in (Settings.ini) do (
set L=22
if !L!=22 set DSuffix1=%%a&& set DSuffix2=%%b&& set DSuffix3=%%c&& set DSuffix4=%%d
)
```

The settings.ini file contains various settings such as the Exchange server and path to the user's home directory. The line I need to interpret is line 22 which looks like this:

DOMAINNAME.SUFFIX(.SUFFIX.SUFFIX.SUFFIX)
A real life example would be:
testlab.local
or
testlab.ghamilton.local

For a testlab the setting should only be the domainname and suffix although for others such as schools or institutions the number of domain suffixes can go up to four. I want to interpret this.

EDIT: Managed to indent code correctly, sorry.

Comment: Sorry if I'm dense, but I'm trying to make sense of this and I don't understand what you're asking!  Can you 1. format your code correctly (indent each code line at least four spaces so SO formats it as code) and 2. provide a sample of the pertinent lines in the settings.ini file, along with 3. what you hope to have as the result from those sample lines.  For example, do you just want to end up with the *number* as your title seems to indicate? Or are you wanting a "vector"?  What's wrong with just %%a, %%b etc?

Comment: I'm unsure how to format the code properly, sorry. I'll include 1 and 2 in the original post. As for three, I hope to have it so that the script finds the number of tokens in the specific line in the Settings file and then adds users through dsadd according to the number of tokens. This would be like three dc sections if there are three tokens, four if there are four tokens etc. I want to store the various domain suffixes as variables because I have other for loops after this one so %%a etc. would not work.

Comment: I just figured out how to format code. Sorry for not doing that previously. Also, I don't see why that deserved a downvote :/

Comment: The downvote was for "it is unclear", and I leave a message explaining what's unclear. Once you fix it up, I undo the downvote (or someone else comes along and upvotes).

Comment: Okay, sorry. My apologies if things seem unclear, my brain isn't working too well today and I have a bit of a cold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have a string such as `domain.foo.bar.baz` and you want to change that to `dc=domain,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=baz`.

How about this?

```
set domain=domain.foo.bar.baz
echo dc=%domain:.=,dc=%
```

That should echo this:

```
dc=domain,dc=foo,dc=bar,dc=baz
```

That `%domain:.=,dc=%` line is expanding the `%domain%` environment variable, but replacing all `.` with `,dc=`.  See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html for more details.

To do string replacement in an environment variable, you do need the value to be in an environment variable first.  Here's a script that will read line 22 from settings.ini, combined with the above technique:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set L=0
for /f %%a in (settings.ini) do (
    set /a L=!L! + 1
    if !L! equ 22 (
        set domain=%%a
        echo dc=!domain:.=,dc=!
    )
)
```

`L` is being used to count what line we're on.  When we reach line 22, we set an environment variable to the value of the entire line (`%%a`), then do the string substitution as above (but with `!` rather than `%` to take advantage of delayed expansion).

Of course instead of an `echo`, you would do something like

```
dsadd "cn=%cn%,ou=%ou%,dc=!domain:.=,dc=!"
```

Comment: Thanks for that Nate. So would that work if I stored the domain as a variable that I had read from the settings file?

Comment: Nate I was wondering if you could help with something else. I have user groups that I need to ad the users to however I want these to be defined in the Settings file. They are separated by comma's and I was wondering if you could do something similar to what you did for the domain. I'd like to add them to groups using net group preferably.

Comment: Sorry, I should have waited a while before writing that. I've done it now. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my little snippet to sort of demonstrate how to get the separate tokens (the delims are space and tab, but you can change them).

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set token1=%%a
    set token2=%%b
    set token3=%%c
    set token4=%%d
    set full=%%a%%b%%c%%d
)
set token
set full
pause>nul
```

`test.txt` contains:

```
first second third
```

The output was:

```
token1=first
token2=second
token3=fourth
full=firstsecondthird
```

So, you could judge how many tokens there is by something like

```
for /l %%i in (4,-1,1) do if not defined token%%i set amount=%%i
```

Or something along the same lines.

Hope that helps.